# nth child animation stopped working

Tags: html, css

Got a weekend poser for you.

I've been working on a new site and I have a little animation in the top right of some letters fading in and out.

They're all in separate spans (the letters) and I'm using .letter:nth-child(number) for each one in the css.

It was all working great but after adding a couple of bits and bobs, suddenly, the 10th letter has stopped working.

I'm staring at the code like a muppet and I've re-written the css and gone through every line but I just can't figure out why it has stopped working.

```
  .letter:nth-child(10) {
        -webkit-animation: fade 4s 

infinite 1000ms;
        animation: fade 4s infinite 

1000ms;
    }
```

I have upped it to jsfiddle and it does the exact same thing there.

https://jsfiddle.net/hj15se3t/1/

Anyone have an idea as to what could be causing it?

Thanks for your time as always and for any help. As usual it'll probably turn out to be something stupid. I'm just stumped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is that there is an extra element before the letters. So what's happening is that `:nth-child(1)` is targeting `<div id="pic">`. You could add a new rule for `:nth-child(11)` or wrap all the letter in their own container to avoid any issue like this happening again in the future should you need to change the layout of the DOM.

Comment: @ Drift You sir, are legend! See, I knew it would turn out to be something silly like that. I didn't realise it would apply to the div first. I thought it would only apply to the letter class. Thank you very much ;-)

Answer (score 0):

wrap all letters in an extra `div` because `nth-child` is going to look at all the children in the parent. Your parent `div` still has the `svg` element as a child too. So `nth-child(10)` is actually the 9th letter and `nth-child(1)` targets your `svg`.

**2 solutions possible:**

- Add `nth-child(11)` to take the 10th letter and remove `nth-child(1)`
- wrap the letters in another `div`.

**DEMO**

https://jsfiddle.net/hj15se3t/2/

Comment: @ Poehah Thanks =) it's the same solution as above. Yeah, I thought it would be an easy fix. I didn't realise that nth child would start with the first thing in the container if I was applying it to the letter class in css. Live and learn. A fool who asks no questions etc!